# Using AngularStrap with AngularMaterial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I have a form created with [AngularMaterial](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input) elements.

There is no time picker in ngMaterial though so I decided to use [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/timepickers).

It is working well except from the visual aspect. The time picker input does no look like the rest of the ngMaterial inputs.

Is there a way to fix this, and make the AngularStrap input elements styled as the rest of my form, using ngMaterial?

Comment: You should take a look at the css used by angular material and override the css of AngularStrap. But I'm not sure you can obtain the exact same design easily

Comment: Doesn't something like that work ? :

    `<md-input-container>
           <label>date</label>
      <input ng-model="myDate" type="email"  data-min-date="{{fromDate}}" placeholder="Until" bs-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>`

Comment: @ThibaudL I normally would but the css of ngStrap is inside it's second js file, so I was not sure I knew how to mess with that.
Your second suggestion works fine, but when I click the input, the resulting popover scales to the size of that input (witch is too small) and so the dates overlap one another. This probably has nothing to do with your solution though so I will try and find the error myself. Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: I've added it, and as suggested I think your issue is adapting both css to work well together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it but you might need to do some small css update to get everything neat :

```
<md-input-container> 
    <label>date</label> 
    <input ng-model="myDate" type="email" data-min-date="{{fromDate}}" placeholder="Until" bs-datepicker> 
</md-input-container>
```